# On click of an <a> tag, show an overlay and follow the href URL of <a> if Yes is selected as an option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to show an overlay on click of a anchor tag. If affirmative <kbd>YES</kbd> response is selected from the overlay options, the default `<a>` tag behaviour should follow with the `href` link opening in new window/current window as required.

**My jquery to show an overlay on click of  tag:**

```
$('a.external-link').click(function() {

var popupid = "popuprel";

$('#' + popupid).fadeIn();

$('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
$('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn();

var popuptopmargin = ($('#' + popupid).height() + 10) / 2;
var popupleftmargin = ($('#' + popupid).width() + 10) / 2;

$('#' + popupid).css({
'margin-top' : -popuptopmargin,
'margin-left' : -popupleftmargin
});

return false;
});
```

**Yes option click function call:**

```
$('.link-continue').click(function() {                          
$('#fade , #popuprel').fadeOut()  
});

<a class = "link-continue">YES</a>
```

Currently  on click of the YES button the overlay closes but how should i redirect it to the URL('href' attribute of the  tag clicked) which is present as the part of the link i clicked.

Comment: where's the question? can't find it.

Comment: Please clarify both your problem and your question.

Comment: @user2806031 [#19549245](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549003/on-click-of-an-a-tag-show-an-overlay-and-follow-the-href-url-of-a-if-yes-is/19549245#19549245) did this worked for you?

Comment: @zur4ik - the solution still din't work. I have added clarity to the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should save your `<a>` url in global variable out of the function:

```
 var linkBuffer;

    $('a.external-link').click(function (e) {

        //prevent browser to follow link
        e.preventDefault();

        //save link
        linkBuffer = $(this).attr('href');

        var popupid = "popuprel";

        $('#' + popupid).fadeIn();

        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
        $('#fade').css({
            'filter': 'alpha(opacity=80)'
        }).fadeIn();

        var popuptopmargin = ($('#' + popupid).height() + 10) / 2;
        var popupleftmargin = ($('#' + popupid).width() + 10) / 2;

        $('#' + popupid).css({
            'margin-top': -popuptopmargin,
            'margin-left': -popupleftmargin
        });
    });
```

So when you click <kbd>Yes</kbd> on your popup, then just change window location:

```
$('.link-continue').click(function () {
    $('#fade , #popuprel').fadeOut();
    document.location.href = linkBuffer;
});
```

---

## Update:

**Here is demo for you:** http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/fzn4Z/

**Please note**, that when you'll click yes on confirmation window, JSFiddle will not allow to load different link (you can check this in console, when you click <kbd>Yes</kbd>), but it will work out of JsFiddle.

Comment: The global variable gets the href attribute correctly but then on click of Yes button no redirection happens. document.location.href = linkBuffer; does not work.

Comment: @Amit it's working for me. Just added JsFiddle demo for you. Try it, maybe you are missing something?

Comment: how can I add a target="_blank" to this?

Comment: @scott.schaffer you can do it with:

`var win = window.open(url, '_blank');` and  `win.focus();`

Answer (score 0):

I would have `$('.link-continue')` as an anchor element styled like button, which has link to the url proposed to navigate, so clicking on `$('.link-continue')` take user to new page in same window. In case you want to open new window, `preventDefault` in click listener of `$('.link-continue')`, and use `window.open` for same `href`.

Answer (score 0):

if `#popupre1` contains `<a class = "link-continue">YES</a>` you can try change your Show overlay function like this

```
$('a.external-link').click(function() {

    var popupid = "popuprel";

    $('#' + popupid).fadeIn().find('.link-continue').attr('href',$(this).attr('href'));

    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn();

    var popuptopmargin = ($('#' + popupid).height() + 10) / 2;
    var popupleftmargin = ($('#' + popupid).width() + 10) / 2;

    $('#' + popupid).css({
        'margin-top' : -popuptopmargin,
        'margin-left' : -popupleftmargin
    });

    return false;
});
```

option click function not changed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.location.href = linkBuffer;
```

using

```
window.open(linkBuffer,'_blank');
```

worked Thanks.

So the code for Continue button click becomes:

```
$('.link-continue').click(function () {
$('#fade , #popuprel').fadeOut();
document.location.href = linkBuffer;
});
```